# How to save state of checkboxes in datatable on navigation in primefaces 3.5

Tags: primefaces

I select checkboxes in the datatable and press button and when i return to the page, it got deselected. i want the selection to be saved after navigation. it is like i select few of the candidates as shortlisted and go next, and if i want to make some changes to amend the list and go back then i want the already checked candidates to be checked but actually when im returning to the page, it refreshes

- button for selection::::

  ```
  <f:param name="currentPage" value="#{nav.ShortListed}" />
  <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{pageManager.prevNavigation}" value="#{nav.New}"  />
  ```

  - code for returning to the same page:

and the respective bean

```
public void revertShortListPanel() throws SQLException
{  
    Session hibernateSession = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
    Connection con = hibernateSession.connection();

    //.............removing all offrs from offr_panel table...........revert short listing
   this.customSelectedOffrs = new ArrayList<CriteriaSearchDao>();
   this.selectedRows = new CriteriaSearchDao[customSelectedOffrs.size()];          
   String sql1 ="delete from OFFR_PANEL where PANEL_ID = ? ";
   String sql2 = "update TBL_PANEL set PANEL_STATUS ='New' where PANEL_ID=? "; 
   PreparedStatement pnlStatus1 = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
   PreparedStatement pnlStatus2 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
```

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related?

Comment: im making project in primefaces. and this is a primefaces...<p:commandButton action="#{criSearchBean.shortListPanel}"
    styleClass="button_style" value="Short List"
    onclick="myTable.clearFilters()" process="@this" ajax="false">

    <f:param name="currentPage" value="#{nav.ShortListed}" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{pageManager.prevNavigation}"
     value="#{nav.New}"  />
   </p:commandButton>

Comment: <p:commandButton action="#{criSearchBean.revertShortListPanel}" styleClass="button_style" 
   value="Need Changes" process="@this" ajax="false" 
   disabled="#{userBean.userTypes!=EXECUTIVE}" >

  <f:param name="currentPage" value="#{nav.New}" />
   <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{pageManager.prevNavigation}" value="#{nav.ShortListed}" /> 
  </p:commandButton>